# How to save a document opened within an SWT OleClientSite in an eclipse EditorPart?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, ole

I started to use the SWT OLE api to edit Word documents in an Eclipse RCP. I created a custom editor wich extends `org.eclipse.ui.part.EditorPart` and which contains an `OleClientSite` object.
The problem is that the save icon is grayed out. Is there a solution to enable that icon?

I also tried to add a `KeyListener` to my `OleClientSite` to catch the Ctrl+s event but it does not seem to work. In debug mode, the breakpoint in the `keyPressed` method is never reached...

I thought I could add a keylistener to my editor but I didn't find how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is OLE object. In OLE, the save menu is disabled, however object can be saved via **save()** method, like that:

```
oleClientSite.save(new File(fileName), true);
```

there is also isDirty() method returning true if object was modified
You need to add your own menu in order to let user save the file.

```
private void addMenu(OleFrame frame, String menuName) {
    final Shell shell = frame.getShell();
    Menu menuBar = shell.getMenuBar();
    if (menuBar == null) {
        menuBar = new Menu(shell, SWT.BAR);
        shell.setMenuBar(menuBar);
    }
    MenuItem fileMenu = new MenuItem(menuBar, SWT.CASCADE);
    fileMenu.setText(menuName);
    Menu menuFile = new Menu(fileMenu);
    fileMenu.setMenu(menuFile);
    frame.setFileMenus(new MenuItem[]{fileMenu});

    MenuItem menuFileOpen = new MenuItem(menuFile, SWT.CASCADE);
    menuFileOpen.setText("Save ...");
    menuFileOpen.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
        oleClientSite.save(new File(fileName), true);

        }
    });
    MenuItem menuFileExit = new MenuItem(menuFile, SWT.CASCADE);
    menuFileExit.setText("Quit");
    menuFileExit.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        shell.dispose();
        }
    });
}

.....
display = new Display();
shell = new Shell(display);
shell.setSize(1000, 700);
shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

oleFrame = new OleFrame(shell, SWT.NONE);
oleClientSite = new OleClientSite(oleFrame, SWT.NONE, new File(fileName));
oleClientSite.doVerb(OLE.OLEIVERB_INPLACEACTIVATE);

addMenu(oleFrame);
```

more details here - http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet262.java

and here http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/

Comment: Thank you for the sample code. My application already has its own menu. So with this sample code, the File menu is added to the menu bar and replace the existing menu entries. But when I click on it, nothing happens. It looks like the File menu is not really activated but I don't know why. Any idea?

Comment: Also, my application implements `IApplication` and the menu is managed by a class which extends `ActionBarAdvisor`.

Comment: it is worth to note, that saving with *oleClientSite.save(new File(fileName), true);* would save the document, but OpenOffice / Libre Office cannot open it, I faced this recently. The solution I found is to unpack the odt file (it is just zip) and pack it back. After this the document is opened properly ... strange and took me some time to figure out.

Comment: For info, I solved my problem adding a permanent save Action to my application toolbar using the `ActionBarAdvisor` class and the `ActionFactory.SAVE.create` method :) When clicked, this action save the activated editor and is grayed when no editor is dirty :)

I also added an accelerator to the action to use the Ctrl+s shortcut but it does not work when the editor has the focus :/ Still, it's better than nothing :)

I added all my application menu items to the file menu of the `OleClientSite`.

Comment: @norbi771 hi, Excel file open and save work proper but second time cann't save the existing excel file, any idea

Comment: @BharatZala Hi, I wish I could help but haven't work on this matter for some time now. What I found in the meantime and is worth to consider is to save files you want to edit using webdav and simply open the editor and edit the file. This approach is used by Confluence as far as I know.